# Getting notified on Firefox extension uninstall

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am currently developing a SDK Firefox extension and wish to do something once the user uninstalls my extension ( for example, clean up storage ). I tried:

```
exports.onUnload = function (reason) {
 if (reason == "uninstall") 
 {
 //do something
 }
}
```

and believed it would work, until I read at [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Listening_for_load_and_unload) (end of article) that due to the bug, I will never be notified of the "uninstall", only disabled.

Now, I know boostraped extensions have the `uninstall` function which will be called correctly. However, if i build my extension with jpm, I can't just tamper with *bootstrap.js* (or can I).

I also tried the following:

```
require("sdk/system/unload").when(function (reason) {
    //do my thing
});
```

but this does the same thing.

Is there a way to go around this bug?

Answer (score 0):

As you said, there is currently a bug with the `onUnload` method so it will never get called with `uninstall` reason parameter.

The only thing you can do is listen for disable. In most cases it will be enough, since a very little percentage of users re-enables extensions after disabling them.